# Ansible: How to create variables from a lookup file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

We have many csv files and contain lookup data for various configurations.

```
#eg of lookup file csv
hostname,ip,country,type,port
atlanta1,1.2.3.4,US,ui,8080
toronto1,1.2.3.5,CA,ui,8080
toronto2,1.2.3.9,CA,db,8000
another3,1.2.3.6,UK,db,8000
```

We need to populate complex & concatenated variables which then needs to be used in other playbooks,

```
# Eg. concatenated variables  http:{{hostname}}:{{port}} from above lookup csv file
ui_cluster = http://atlanta1:8080;http://toronto1:8080
db_cluster = http://atlanta1:8000;http://toronto1:8000
```

.. And finally the concatenated variables are used in final playbooks

```
#configurations in final customer template
my_build_script_UIcluster= {{ui_cluster}}
my_build_script_DBcluster= {{db_cluster}}
```

I want to use such variables which are created from above lookup to be used within the templates. How to do this or best approach for this?

Comment: Please explain what is a "*lookup file*" for a start.

Comment: hi lookup is just a csv file which I've put as an example in the post.

Comment: So you just used a name "*lookup file*" for a regular file, right? Possibly to confuse readers (and search engines' users) with Ansible [lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html), right? And by "*from above lookup*" you don't mean actually a lookup. Great communication skills!

Comment: hope to get some technical answers rather than communication skills lesson. Will wait for few days for other helpful folks out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `include_csv` module https://github.com/mkouhei/ansible-role-includecsv sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[jinja2 csv lookup filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html#the-csv-file-lookup)**:

> The csvfile lookup reads the contents of a file in CSV
>   (comma-separated value) format. The lookup looks for the row where the
>   first column matches keyname, and returns the value in the second
>   column, unless a different column is specified.
>
> *(from the official documentation)*

The lookup filter returns an array where each line is represented by a key value object. You can use the **[jinja2 map filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#map)** to create a list of one key's value:

> Applies a filter on a sequence of objects or looks up an attribute.
>   This is useful when dealing with lists of objects but you are really
>   only interested in a certain value of it.
>
> *(from the official documentation)*

This should be everything you need altough not a copy and paste answer.

Comment: hi max, I've done the lookup filter already and if I use the variables it works. But I want to create complex variables in between and then use these complex/concatenated variables for final template

Comment: You can use `set_fact` to dynamically add facts. Jinja2 template strings can be used in there. If you update your question to include the actual ansible code you've written so far I can try to figure something out.